# Why am I seeing "member function with the same name as its class must be a constructor"?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

I had a useful function that I wanted to convert from a standalone utility into a RAII-style helper class. My definition of the class goes well until I paste in the function code and rename it. At this point the function name is underlined in red, and the tooltip says "member function with the same name as its class must be a constructor".

This error message is not helpful. I **know** that I can't write a function with the same name as the class. I **want** this function to be a constructor. Why isn't it? What's going on?

Before:

```
void Useful( int Param ) // works, and is useful
{
    // do useful things
}
```

After:

```
class Useful
{
    void Useful( int Param ) // generates error
    {
        // do useful things
    }
};
```

Comment: What is unclear about that error message? Constructor functions don't have a return type (that's covered in every beginners book). I don't think that's such a common error that it deserves it's own Q&A pair here.

Comment: Nah. Instead I'll nag you. *This error message is not helpful.* Yet it told you exactly what's wrong. You want it to be a constructor, yet clearly to the compiler it's not a constructor. Compare the function against the signature of a constructor and Whammo! The return type really stands out.

Comment: I wrote this Q/A pair because searching for error messages usually brings me to a helpful entry on SO and in this case I couldn't find a good answer anywhere. I'm hoping it will help somebody else.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is a cut and paste error. It is the presence of the return type that prevents the function being interpreted as a constructor.

So:

```
class Useful
{
    Useful( int Param ) // problem solved
    {
        // do useful things
    }
};
```